# Don't have OnActivated method in app.xaml.cs Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, states

I'm actually working on an application which was a blank Windows Phone app 8.1 at the beginning. I wanted to implement the app with a FileOpenPicker to get a picture from the device. In WP 8.1, I have to use ***PickSingleFileAndContinue*** method of the OpenFilePicker. So I've read about configuring my project to handle ***Continue*** event here: [your Windows Phone Store app after calling an AndContinue method MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631755.aspx). One of the steps is to implement the OnActivated method in the app.xaml.cs file.**But there is no OnActivated method in my app.xaml.cs.**

I've copy paste that method from the above link but the MainPage object used in that method doesn't have a Current state:

```
 protected async override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnActivated(e);

        continuationManager = new ContinuationManager();

        Frame rootFrame = CreateRootFrame();
        await RestoreStatusAsync(e.PreviousExecutionState);

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        }

        var continuationEventArgs = e as IContinuationActivatedEventArgs;
        if (continuationEventArgs != null)
        {
            Frame scenarioFrame = MainPage.Current.FindName("ScenarioFrame") as Frame;
            if (scenarioFrame != null)
            {
                // Call ContinuationManager to handle continuation activation
                continuationManager.Continue(continuationEventArgs, scenarioFrame);
            }
        }

        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

As I'm knew to Windows Phone and just facing the states management of an app, I cannot really figure out where that error comes from. Maybe someone got an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

It won't be 100% clear until you download the full source code example off that link.  They neglected to post the full example (too much code).  Download the C# demo project and look at it.

[MSDN FilePicker FULL SOURCE](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-picker-sample-9f294cba)

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public static MainPage Current;        

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();            

        // This is a static public property that allows downstream pages to get a handle to the MainPage instance
        // in order to call methods that are in this class.
        Current = this;            

        Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
    }
}
```

As you can see it's just a static declaration.

Comment: The thing is that I've deleted the page MainPage.xaml because i don't need it. So I understood that it's sometimes usefull to have a blank page, so I created back th MainPage.xaml. I added to it the static MainPage declaration by still getting the same error on the App.xaml.cs: **MainPage is highlighted as it doesn't have a "Current" component...**

Comment: @HubertSolecki post your MainPage.xaml.cs  (the entire file), I can not see this happen unless something weird is going on.  Or you can just delete that file and Add -> New Item -> Visual C# -> Windows Phone Portrait Page.  Name that MainPage.xaml